# How do I use sed to replace a line?

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the line

```
"['Used', 170], <c\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->"
```

with

```
"['Used', 555], <c\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->"
```

in a html file.

This is what I tried.

```
sed "s/['Used', 170], <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->/['Used', 170], <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->/" Code_edit.html
```

Tried with multiple masking. Not helping.

Comment: you only need this ` sed 's/170/555/'`

Comment: The way that you have it works for me.

Comment: Hi Goro, In fact the file has multiple similar statements with value 170. That is why I've added a comment <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used--> to identify each line. Unfortunately I can't use sed 's/170/555/' here.

Comment: Hi Nasir...Please note an error in my previous sed comment. Correct one : sed "s/['Used', 170], <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->/['Used', 500], <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->/" Code_edit.html

Answer (score 0):

On `sed` there are some characters with special meaning, those need to be quoted.
On this sentence:

```
['Used', 170], <\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->
```

You need to quote `[`, `]` and `\`:

```
\['Used', 170\], <\\\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->
```

Then, to capture the text surrounding the number, add capture parenthesis:

```
\(\['Used', \)170\(\], <\\\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->\)
```

And convert the `170` into `[0-9]*` (a list of numbers).
Having done that, the sed command becomes:

```
sed "s/\(\['Used', \)[0-9]*\(\], <\\\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->\)/\1777\2/" <file
```

The `\1` and `\2` use the strings captured in each parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
sed '/!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->/ s/170/555/' file
"['Used', 555], <c\!--Ma_P_ST1_vCPU_Used-->"
```

Search for the right line, and then replace 170 with 555.